# supports-screens tag appears after application tag?

Tags: android, manifest

The following problems are reported in Eclipse since my latest update of SDK and Eclipse. What does this mean? Where should I place the supports-screens tag?

> <supports-screens> tag appears after <application> tag

This is a typical manifest of my apps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal" 
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.1"
    package="aa.bb.cc" >

    <application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/cc"
        android:label="@string/txt_appname"
        android:name="MyApplication" >

        <activity
            android:name="ActivityA" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="ActivityB" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="MoreActivities"></activity>

        <service android:name="MyService"></service>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) contains the optimal layout of the manifest.

Comment: Yes, but the Docs state too: Elements at the same level are generally not ordered. supports-screens and applcation are on the same level.

Comment: Well, as said: *Optimal*. It's not required. This is just a warning, not an error. Keep it there and you will be fine. But optimally you will move it to the top to get rid of the warning. *(similar as indenting your code properly is a convention, this is too. Feel free not to do it.)*

Comment: Yes, thanks. Yet another warning I have to live with. I do prefer alphabetical order on all elements where order is not neccessary. Even my layout files are ordered completely. I still write them by myself - no layout tool.

Answer (score 2):

I think **support screens** tag should before the application tag.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a typo or have u missed a quote there under the application tag, maybe that is causing this error:

```
android:icon="@drawable/cc
```

should be

```
android:icon="@drawable/cc"
```

Comment: This is a typo in the sample I've put here - thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Can you try cleaning your project and then running it again? :)

Comment: I did clean so many times. In fact I have to clean all my 13 projects after every Eclipse restart - something I live with since nearly three years now. Regarding the problem: Seems that the doc explanation "order not neccessary on elements sharing the same level" and the checker "order is neccessary for uses-screens and application" don't talk the same language.

Comment: I created a blank project on my laptop and tried adding the <supports-screens> tag before, after and in the middle of the <application> tag, works every time!

Comment: Do you have latest SDK, Eclipse? Did you change the Lint settings? My environment is on the latest releases and Lint is unmodified. Immediately after my comments here I did reorder all my Manifest files according to the docs and the warnings went away. These warnings were new to me - must be one of the latest updates of SDK or Eclipse.

Comment: Latest SDK, everything is on stock.

Comment: Funny. Thanks anyway. Seems that we will not find a reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

Placing it as the first child of the manfest (as shown in the documentation) resolved the issue.